# Choosing ARMA parameters - is my process right?

Tags: self-study, arima, model-selection, finance

I have been practicing choosing the correct ARMA models for data & feel I may be doing something wrong. I have yielded the same answer for every single stock -ARMA(0,0). I just wanted to confirm if that sounds odd?

My steps include:
1-download stock price
2-convert to daily log returns
3- check for stationarity
4 - analysis ACF & PAF

The ACF/PAC always show no autocorrelation so I conclude ARMA(0,0). However, when I practice with the class data I always get correlations so I am able to further estimate the ARMA parameters - does it sound right to you?

Thanks1

Comment: Is your case somehow different from dozens of previous questions on order selection of ARIMA models? You might very well learn something useful from checking those threads out.

Comment: I have learned a lot from those dozens of threads regarding the selection of ARIMA - But still didn't find an answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the tools of arima model identification , the ACF and PACF are notoriously effected by possible pulses,level shifts,seasonal pulses and/or local time trends in the data. In order to "see" the form of the arima model you need to 1) have data that has no missing values like holidays   2) is free of aforementioned deterministic structure  etc. To prove/test my point simulate an AR(1) process and note the ACF and PACF exhibit expected structure .... then throw in some pulses/level shifts,seasonal pulses,time trends into the data and see what the resultant ACF and PACF look like . Lo and behold you will find ( depending on the # of injected interruptions and their magnitude that the distorted ACF and PACF is a poor guide to the underlying/true model